# Correct pattern doesn't work in Lua gmatch

Tags: lua

For example we have a string

```
local str = "12345:some.address.ru:1234"
```

And we need parse this string as:

```
var1 = "12345"   -- mandatory
var2 = "some.address.ru"  -- can be nil
var3 = "1234"   -- can be nil
```

I've written such code:

```
for var1, var2, var3 in str:gmatch('^(%d+)%:?([%a.]*)%:(%d+)$') do
print(var1)
print(var2)
print(var3)
end
```

but I doesn't receive any result. And if I delete simbol ^ in the beginning of the pattern it works well.
What 's the problem? Why doesn't it work with simbol ^ and how can I fix it?
(I need to check that this pattern starts from beginning of the string)

And is there any chance to do this work without for loop?
(My string doesn't contain more then 1 pattern)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) says this about `gmatch`:

> a caret '^' at the start of a pattern does not work as an anchor, as this would prevent the iteration.

You don’t need a loop and so don't need `gmatch`. Just do

```
var1, var2, var3=str:match('(%d+)%:?([%a.]*)%:(%d+)$')
print(var1)
print(var2)
print(var3)
```

Adding `^` to the pattern is harmless.

A simpler pattern is `'(.-):(.-):(.-)$’`.

Note that in both cases you don’t need to anchor the pattern at the beginning but you do need to anchor it at the end.